# How to block redirect http to https in gitlab server?

Tags: http, https, port, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I'm hosting gitlab-ce on my server and I want to disable redirecting HTTP -> HTTPS
in another word I want to free up my port(80)
I've already changed this config in gitlab.rb:

> nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false

but it didn't work.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

By default, GitLab will listen on the port specified in `external_url`; 80 by default if there's no explicit port number.

There are two ways to change the port number:

1. Add a port number to `external_url` like `https://gitlab.example.com:8080`
2. Set `nginx['listen_port']` -- this useful when you are behind a reverse-proxy and want to change the listen port, but not use the port number in the hostname. This will probably cause issues if you're not using a reverse proxy!

You can also disable https by setting `nginx['listen_https'] = false`

See [gitlab nginx settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#verbosity-level-of-nginx-logs) for more details.